# lightning:input Date is behaving different in desktop and mobile

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, slds

I have a simple lightning:input type="date" in aura component and it is behaving different in desktop vs mobile. Can someone suggest how o make it consistent across both. Preferred is I see mm/dd/yyyy in desktop too. or hide  mm/dd/yyyy in mobile using CSS?

Here is the sample code.
DateCheck.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="birthDate" type="Date" access="private"/>
      Lightning
     <br/>
    <lightning:input type="date" label="Test"
                                 aura:id="requiredInput"
                                 ariaLabel="Lightning Test"
                                 value="{!v.birthDate}"
                                 />
</aura:component>
```

In Desktop:

[image]

In Mobile it behaves different:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation):

> On desktop, lightning:input provides its own date picker that's styled with the Lightning Design System. On mobile devices it uses the native date picker which has different styling.

---

I think you can use the `placeholder` attribute to get the same "mm/dd/yyyy" text on both.

Comment: place holder is just text, but the mobile version mm/dd/yyyy works with tab and changes based on country locale.